# How can I include all package dependencies in an R package?

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I searched all over the place, but couldn't find an answer. I am creating my own R functions, but these have CRAN package dependencies. Is there a way to package all the dependent CRAN R package binaries into my R package?

I need to do this because our centralized machine that runs these R scripts don't have internet access. We simply deploy it to run our scripts.

Comment: Add your own repository on that central machine to the options values in your `.profile.site` file for "repos" so that `getOption("repos")` will search your local site.

Answer (score 1):

No, the idea is to have *repository* containing the other packages which your package depends upon.

The CRAN packages miniCRAN and drat help with, respectfully, finding that set of packages and hosting / accessing it.

Comment: miniCRAN works, however pkgDep() is unable to decipher my package's DESCRIPTION or NAMESPACE file to get all the packages which contains a Depends line and imports(), respectively. Can you or someone please point me to an example where miniCRAN::pkgDep(...) can read a custom package's dependencies?

Comment: The error thrown by pkgDep is "No valid packages in pkg".